# Abstract of a book

Tags: abstract

I am using format as following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\textheight 9in \textwidth 6.5in \topmargin 0.1in \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.1in}
\evensidemargin .1in

\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{{\footnotesize Accident Detection, Theft and Drive Protection using Intelligent Wireless Safety Helmet}}
\lfoot{Department of E\&C, S.I.T., Tumakuru-3}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\rhead{2014-15}
\linespread{1.5}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Abstract}
Now a days most of the countries are enforcing their citizen to wear helmet while riding bike and not to ride bike when the person is under the influence of alcohol, but still rules are being violated. In order to overcome this problem, " Accident Detection, Theft and Drive Protection using Intelligent Wireless Safety Helmet " is developed. It consists of an intelligent system embedded into the helmet and the vehicle. Helmet unit ensures that rider is wearing helmet and not under influence of alcohol through out the ride. It communicates with vehicle unit to switch off ignition system of bike if above condition is not met. Vehicle unit checks and intimates accident through geometric coordinates via SMS. By using geometric coordinates, location of the injured rider can be traced using simple GPS tracking application. Also, this system provide theft protection as helmet is also essential along with key to start bike.

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
```

and I am getting abstract with page number in table of contents.
But desired output should contain Abstract in `bold` in Table of Content without page number.

Please help to sort out this problem.

Comment: Aside, don't implement the abstract as a section. At least in `article`, `{abstract}` already exists as an environment. I would take cue for that. Try re-compiling; TOC is two-pass.

Answer (score 3):

You have used `\chapter*{Abstract}` and then `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}` which will put `Abstract` as a section. What do you want exactly?

I suggest you to use `frontmatter` `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` facilities provided by `book` class. Then you won't need `\chapter*` and hence `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}` line. Just `\Chapter{Abstract}` will do both the jobs.

Further to remove page numbers for abstract in the toc, use `tocloft` package and its `\cftpagenumbersoff` facility like

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
```

before `Abstract` and

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}
```

after it.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\chapter{Abstract}
Now a days most of the countries are enforcing their citizen to wear helmet while riding bike and not to ride bike when the person is under the influence of alcohol, but still rules are being violated. In order to overcome this problem, " Accident Detection, Theft and Drive Protection using Intelligent Wireless Safety Helmet " is developed. It consists of an intelligent system embedded into the helmet and the vehicle. Helmet unit ensures that rider is wearing helmet and not under influence of alcohol through out the ride. It communicates with vehicle unit to switch off ignition system of bike if above condition is not met. Vehicle unit checks and intimates accident through geometric coordinates via SMS. By using geometric coordinates, location of the injured rider can be traced using simple GPS tracking application. Also, this system provide theft protection as helmet is also essential along with key to start bike.

\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]